# AM-GM & Minimization Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I want to prove that for all $x, y > 0$, $$\cfrac{x+y}{2} \geq \sqrt{xy}$$
Particularly, I want to show that the minimum of $(x+y)/2$ is exactly $\sqrt{xy}$.

This is my attempt:

$\textbf{Proof}$ (Contradiction). Assume if $x, y > 0$, then $(x+y)/2 < \sqrt{xy}$. But
\begin{align*}
x+y &< 2\sqrt{xy} \\
x^2+2xy+y^2 &< 4xy \\
x^2-2xy+y^2 &< 0 \\
(x-y)^2 &< 0
\end{align*}
gives us a contradiction since for all $x, y > 0$, we know $(x-y)^2 > 0$. Therefore there exists no positive reals $x$ and $y$ such that $(x+y)/2 < \sqrt{xy}$, or $\min\bigg(\cfrac{x+y}{2}\bigg) = \sqrt{xy}$. $\qquad \square$

Comment: No. The minimum can not be an "expression". It must be only a finite number. Indeed, you can also write $$x+y+1≥3\sqrt [3]{xy}\implies \frac {x+y}{2}≥\frac {3\sqrt [3]{xy}-1}{2}$$ Therefore, the minimum can not be considered as a non-constant expression.

Comment: Your claim about the minimum is false. With $x, y > 0$ the LHS has no minimum and gets arbitrarily close to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of talking about minimum, we may say that the inequality
$$\frac{x+y}{2} \geq \sqrt{xy}$$
holds for any $x, y>0$ and the equality holds for $x=y.$

We may prove the inequality directly by starting with $$
\begin{aligned}
& x+y-2 \sqrt{x y}=(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2 \geqslant 0 \\
\Rightarrow \quad  & x+y \geqslant 2 \sqrt{x y} \\
\Rightarrow \quad  & \frac{x+y}{2} \geqslant \sqrt{x y}
\end{aligned}
$$

By the way, we can say that the minimum value $x+y-2\sqrt{xy} $ is  $ 0$ for positive values of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

I think your statement is even incorrect. The quantity $\sqrt{xy}$ is not a constant. Also, it depends on the domain which may or may not yield a minimum. For example, over $[1,\infty)\times [1,\infty)$ then there is a minimum. But over $(1,\infty)\times (1,\infty)$ there is no minimum.